# Watij Click an Image

Tags: java, html, testing, automated-tests, watij

I am trying to click an image during automated testing using Watij. I am specifically trying to use SymbolFactory's src (instead of name, id, etc.) as detection.

HTML:

```
<input type="image" src="lib/img/btnFindStore.png" style="border-width:0px;">
```

Java:

```
ie.image(SymbolFactory.src, "lib/img/btnFindStore.png").click();
```

I am wondering why it throws watij.runtime.UnknownObjectException at this line.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, so using ie.button here is the solution

```
ie.button(SymbolFactory.src, "lib/img/btnFindStore.png").click();
```